# Can I manage/create users in Amazon Elasticache for Redis using native Redis commands?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have many Amazon ElasticCache for Redis clusters deployed in cluster mode (using the default user).

We need to introduce RBAC so we can create monitoring users with the least access possible.

I have tried creating new users through:

- Python Libraries (`redis-py-cluster`): this doesn't work as the create/list user methods are blocked in cluster mode
- `redis-cli`: this doesn't work as the `SETUSER` command keeps coming back with invalid argument errors (even when copying simple examples from the official Redis website)

Is user management for Amazon ElasticCache for Redis only possible via & exclusive to the AWS console/CLI/SDKs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User management in Amazon Elasticache for Redis clusters is managed *exclusively* through the AWS Console / CLI / SDKs, regardless of if you're using Redis AUTH or RBAC via IAM. You have to use the Amazon-provided abstractions on top like [`create-user`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/elasticache/create-user.html).

**You can't manage them manually.**

The `SETUSER` (`acl setuser`) command is also explicitly restricted (disabled) within Elasticache for Redis, as per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/RestrictedCommands.html).

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much.